# Dynamically load (web component) custom elements into Blazor app

Tags: blazor, web-component, blazor-webassembly, es6-modules

We have some nice JavaScript web components developed with custom elements so from HTML we can write e.g.

```
<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
```

These have been wrapped into Blazor control components in a Razor Class Library.
I can use these in Blazor app if I load the web component's JS in the containing Blazor app's index.html, e.g.

```
<script src="_content/MyRazorClassLibrary/components/my-custom-element.js"></script>
```

Then I can reference the Blazor control wrappers in my Blazor app, e.g.

```
<MyCustomElement></MyCustomElement>
```

Lovely. However, I don’t want to load every component's JS in my Blazor app on start-up.  Instead I’d like to load them dynamically if and when they are needed.

Is it possible to update Blazor’s HTML parser with new custom element information after Blazor is loaded - perhaps using JavaScript Isolation to import via ES6 modules or some other way?

It seems that this is actually not possible and that I really have only two options:

- Load all JS in index.html (even though they might not be needed)
- Use JavaScript isolation to construct the the web components from a div via a JavaScript function call on the isolated module (and not use HTML custom elements).

Comment: ?? You want back-end C#/.Net code to (up front) know what the front-end (later) is going to change dynamically??

Comment: Yes - I'd like to know if it is possible yet.  I know .NET 7 introduces official support for registering Blazor components as custom elements, so as custom elements are supported this way it would seem that their use in the "opposite direction" might also be either possible or in the pipeline.

Comment: I think you can with the _Flux Capacitor_ There is a time dependency here. The Front-End is driven by the Back-End, not the other way around. What you want is the Past (backend/Blazor) to know what is going to happen in the Future (front-end/Web Components)